# Pygame: getting a loop to run after mouse click

Tags: python, pygame, mouseclick-event

I want to get a certain loop to run after the mouse has previously been clicked.
I initiated a variable called mouse_clicked to false, and then change it to True after the mouse has been clicked. However, this doesn't seem to get things going afterwards.
Here's my code:

```
import sys, pygame

size = width, height = 320, 240
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

running = True
mouse_pressed = False

while running:
    while mouse_pressed:
        rect = pygame.Rect(10, 20, 30, 30)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), rect)
        pygame.display.flip()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_pressed = True
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False    
sys.exit(0)
```

Thanks!
omer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED** after answering too quickly

move your loop around:

```
while running:
    rect = pygame.Rect(10, 20, 30, 30)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), rect)
    pygame.display.flip()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_pressed = True
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False   

    while mouse_pressed:
        # do your stuff
        mouse_pressed = False
```

In your version, the whole loop never starts, since `mouse_pressed` is initialized to False.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your second loop is not even starting: you are initiating mouse_pressed as False. Therefore,

```
while mouse_pressed
```

will necessarily stop the loop before it ever began. 
Hope this helps!